VS Code React File Name Discrepancy
I faced an issue while working in React. Initially, I created a file named card.jsx and imported it into my App.js file. Later on, I decided to rename card.jsx to Card.jsx and tried to import the updated file. Strangely, despite the code running correctly, VS Code showed an error in the editor regarding the import statement.
When I reverted the filename back to card.jsx, the error disappeared in the editor. However, when running the code, it resulted in a "file does not exist" error.
I found a workaround by creating another file with the same code but a different name and importing it into the desired file, which resolved the issue temporarily.
However, I'm still curious about why this discrepancy occurred in the first place.

Is there any chance you're working from a mac?
By default, HFS+ volumes are case insensitive. While the OS does
preserve the case of filenames, 'filename_cap' is the same as 'filename_CAP' as far as the OS is concerned, so it doesn't change the file name.
So renaming the file, does not actually rename the file in the os.

Does the code persist after restart? could just be an update issue. Filenames don't change that often and the IDE might be slow to parse them.

Maybe some sort of cache, reloading the window might work I guess

Hey everyone, thank you for your suggestions. I restarted the server, and now it's showing the correct output. However, the error in VS Code is still persisting.
